# php to mysql data lost if sequence of code is changed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange thing happening with my input into a mysql data base from a php script. I have shortened my code to the minimum to show what is happening. When I run the first snippet of code below the store data 'Fruitveg' does not get put into the database. The letter 'k' does instead which was taken from var $item[2] leaks.

But if I change the order of event to the second snippet below and make the store variable the first part of this code it works all ok and the store 'Fruitveg' is placed in the database all ok. I have tried to work out what is wrong but cannot get an answer.

Any help please

Snippet One

```
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit();
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO shopping_list (item, store, qty, prefex ) VALUES 
  (:item, 
  :store, :qty, :prefex )";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $item[0] = "2";
  $item[1] = "g";
  $item[2] = "leaks";
  $item[3] = "Fruieveg";
  echo $item[3];

  $qty = $item[0];
  $prefex = $item[1];
  $item = $item[2];
  $store = $item[3]; #when here only letter 'k' is inputted into mysql
  $stmt->bindParam(':store', $store);
  $stmt->bindParam(':item', $item);
  $stmt->bindParam(':qty', $qty);
  $stmt->bindParam(':prefex', $prefex);
  $stmt->execute();
  $conn = null; 
  ?>
```

Snippet Two

```
<?php
# Connect to data base
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=shopping', 'phpmyadmin', 
'Odiham');

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO shopping_list (item, store, qty, prefex ) VALUES 
(:item, :store, :qty, :prefex )";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$item[0] = "2";
$item[1] = "g";
$item[2] = "leaks";
$item[3] = "Fruieveg";
echo $item[3];

$store = $item[3]; #when here only letter 'k' is inputted into mysql
$qty = $item[0];
$prefex = $item[1];
$item = $item[2];
$stmt->bindParam(':store', $store);
$stmt->bindParam(':item', $item);
$stmt->bindParam(':qty', $qty);
$stmt->bindParam(':prefex', $prefex);
$stmt->execute();
$conn = null;   
?>
```

Comment: `$item = $item[2];` Did you mean to do that? Oh wait, I think I see.

Comment: I cant believe that, I have been staring at this all night and missed this. I think I am going blind. Ive changed $item to a different variable and its working, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing your original `$item` array with one of its cells:

```
$item = $item[2]; // $item becomes leaks
$store = $item[3]; // $store gets 4th letter from leaks - 'k'
```

When you change the order, you're correctly setting $store from the original $item array before you replace the $item variable, so that's why it works.

For the DB field,  try using something like `name` instead of item... then you can avoid this accidental overwriting

Comment: Thank you I missed this, and was looking over this all night, I think I need new glasses